# "Belong to" or "belong on"

Tags: prepositions

When I was flagging a post on English Language & Usage Stack Exchange, I found this statement containing phrase "belongs on":

"This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network."

I didn't find "belong on" on any dictionary, even its usage percentage is zero as compared to "belong to" on Google ngram site.

Is it still fine to use preposition "on" instead of "to" to refer anyone's relation with others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both prepositions are fine, but there is a difference in meaning.

> This question belongs *on* another site in the Stack Exchange network.

The question should be moved to the other site.

This sense of [*belong*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/belongs) is "1. suitable, appropriate, or advantageous."

> This question belongs *to* another site in the Stack Exchange network.

The question already *is* on the other site.

This sense of [*belong*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/belongs) is "2. the property of a person or thing."

Answer (score 2):

The verb 'belong' as used here means 'to be in the right place or a suitable place'. You can follow it with many prepositions of place or location such as in, on, under, over, etc. That dishonest man belongs in prison. That picture belongs above the fireplace.

> Dirty boots do not **belong on** the table, now do they?

[Belong (Cambridge)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/belong)

Comment: Your answer seems helpful, but I have still doubts. Why Google ngram site doesn't show its usage?

Comment: Google ngrams show a significant number of examples when I try: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=belongs+on%2Cbelongs+with%2Cbelongs+above%2Cbelongs+in%2Cbelongs+at&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbelongs%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbelongs%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbelongs%20above%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbelongs%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbelongs%20at%3B%2Cc0 (with a few other prepositions for comparison). Maybe you mistyped it when you tried?

Comment: @JamesRandom I think you are right.

Answer (score 2):

Another consideration for your question is how different prepositions are used in different contexts

e.g. in summer vs. on/at the weekend etc.

While 'belong to' certainly has the meaning of possession, and 'belong on' has the meaning of 'appropriate for', you could also use 'belong in' or 'belong at' depending on the noun it precedes.

e.g. This artefact belongs in a museum.    These children belong at home.

Answer (score -1):

Yes both the propositions are obviously correct but you might see there is a slight difference between their meanings.
The word with is used after the word belong especially when you're going to show relation of or connect two things
Consider this example
You belong with me , says Taylor Swift.